# How to link to an action without a route helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

How do I link to an action without a route helper?

I have a route

```
get '/batches/:id/creation_wizard/add_funds' => 'batch::creation_wizard#add_funds'
```

If I do in the Rails console

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
default_url_options[:host] = "localhost"
url_for(controller: 'batch::creation_wizard', action: 'add_funds', id: 1)
```

I get `"http://localhost/batches/1/creation_wizard/add_funds"`

But if I have in

```
class Batch::CreationWizardController < ApplicationController
  def my_method
    redirect_to controller: 'batch/creation_wizard', action: 'add_funds', id: 1
  end
end
```

I get

```
No route matches {:controller=>"batch/batch::creation_wizard", :action=>"add_funds", :id=>1}
```

and if I try

```
redirect_to controller: 'creation_wizard', action: 'add_funds', id: 1
```

I get

```
No route matches {:controller=>"batch/creation_wizard", :action=>"add_funds", :id=>1}
```

and if I try

```
redirect_to action: 'add_funds', id: 1
```

I get

```
No route matches {:action=>"add_funds", :id=>1, :controller=>"batch/creation_wizard"}
```

I tried reading the Rails guide "Rails Routing from the Outside In", and "Getting Started with Rails", and I didn't notice anything that helped.

I could change the routing to

```
get '/batches/:id/creation_wizard/add_funds' => 'batch::creation_wizard#add_funds', as: :creation_wizard_add_funds
```

and rely upon the route helper, but that feels hacky.

I'm using Rails 3.2.22.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The route needs to be changed to

```
get '/batches/:id/creation_wizard/add_funds' => 'batch/creation_wizard#add_funds'
```

What I don't get is why I was able to view a page with `http://localhost:3000/batches/521/creation_wizard/add_funds` in the first place if the routing was wrong.

The Rails guides for version 4.x [mentions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use)

> For namespaced controllers you can use the directory notation. For
>   example:
>
> resources :user_permissions, controller: 'admin/user_permissions' This
>   will route to the Admin::UserPermissions controller.
>
> Only the directory notation is supported. Specifying the controller
>   with Ruby constant notation (eg. controller: 'Admin::UserPermissions')
>   can lead to routing problems and results in a warning.

but unfortunately that doesn't seem to be mentioned in the [equivalent section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/routing.html#customizing-resourceful-routes) in the 3.2.x version of the Rails guides.

Answer (score 0):

This will fix it:

```
class Batch::CreationWizardController < ApplicationController
  def my_method
    redirect_to controller: 'batch::creation_wizard', action: 'add_funds', id: 1
  end
end
```

---

The problem you have is a confusion between [namespaced](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing) and [nested](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) resources.

`Namespacing` is meant to give you the functionality of a *module* (IE keeping a certain level of functionality tied to a specific type of resource):

```
#config/routes.rb
namespace :batch do 
   resources :creation_wizard do
      get :add_funds, on: :member
   end
end
```

This will create the following routes:

```
{action: "show", controller:"batch::creation_wizard", id: "1"}
```

Namespacing is basically there to provide a folder for you to put controllers into. It's most commonly used for `admin` functionality, allowing you to use the likes of:

```
#config/routes.rb
namespace :admin do
   root "application#index"
end

#app/controllers/admin/application_controller.rb
class Admin::ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   ...
end
```

This is what you have currently.

--

If you want to use *nested* routes (IE using a "top level" resource to influence a "lower level" resource), you'll have to change your routes to the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :batches do
   resources :creation_wizard do
      get :add_funds, on: :member
   end
end
```

This will provide the following routes:

```
{controller: "creation_wizard", action: "add_funds", batch_id: params[:batch_id]}
```

Nested resources allow you to define "top" level information (in this case, `batch_id`, which will then trickle down to the called controller. The route will look like `url.com/batches/:batch_id/creation_wizard/add_funds`

Comment: Why didn't `redirect_to action: 'add_funds', id: 1` work in the example I gave?